# bitbucket - The authenticity of host 'bitbucket.org' can't be established

Tags: ssh, bitbucket

I've been getting this issue when trying to push to my bitbucket repo, not sure why the fingerprints don't match:

[image: http://imgur.com/38p8n]
[image: http://imgur.com/3B35N]
It asks me if I want to continue, but I can't type anything in the dialog after hitting ok. Any insight? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I had the same problem..found that this happens because bitbucket.org is not in the Known Host list .
these are steps from the scratch...
(Assumed you are using EGit with Eclipse and have configured ssh keys)

EDIT:
**To Create Local Repository**

1.Right click project ->Team -> Share Project 

2. Select GIT from the menu click next (Ignore message "HOME environment variable not set..")

3.Select use or Create repo. in parent folder...and select the project

4.hit create repo. button -> finish

**1.In Eclipse Open the Git Repository View**
  
 
Window->show view->other->Git->Git Repository

[image: Git Repository View]

**2.Enter repo name**
  [image: Enter Repo Name]

**3.From next window click ADD button enter repository uri the click finish**

[image]

**4.Now click the Dry Run Button and you should get the following dialog
click YES and bitbucket will be added to known hosts**

[image]

**5.Finaly click save and push button**

Comment: wft why is this so bugsome? This saved me today!